# Copy title of the active window to the clipboard in Microsoft Windows

Tags: windows, window-manager, clipboard

I am looking for a Microsoft Windows program that can copy the title of the selected window to the clipboard. Preferably, with a keyboard shortcut.  Any license or price is fine.

Comment: hmmm... there must be a .NET or similar way to do so.

Comment: related - https://superuser.com/questions/378790/how-to-get-window-title-in-windows-from-shell

Answer (score 5):

You can use a script to do it with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (free scripting language for desktop automation on Windows):

```
^!l::
WinGetActiveTitle, Title
Clipboard = %Title%
return
```

Comment: What does ! mean in AutoHotKey? ^ means control,  so what the hot key actually is?

Comment: ! is Alt modifier https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm
The whole hotkey shortcut is therefore Ctrl + Alt + L

Answer (score 0):

You can use a voice command in Dragon NaturallySpeaking (non-free).

Code from [PGilm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38514457/395857):

```
'
'   get window title
'
Sub Main
    Clipboard ( GetWindowTitle )
End Sub
'
'   Use these Windows Functions for Getting an active Window title
'
Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
'
Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" _
    Alias "GetWindowTextA" ( ByVal hwnd As Long , _
        ByVal lpString As String , ByVal cch As Long ) As Long
'
'   GetWindowTitle
'   (Gets an active Window title)
'
Function GetWindowTitle() As String
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim TitleText As String * 300
    Dim hw As Long
    hw = GetForegroundWindow()
    x = GetWindowText ( hw , TitleText , Len ( TitleText ) )
    GetWindowTitle = Trim ( Left ( TitleText , x ) )
End Function
'
```

[image]